# Position: fixed not working as expected when scrolling down

Tags: html, css

I have an element with the class of `.it` that I want to fix in place on the screen using the `position: fixed CSS` property. However, when I scroll down the page, the element moves up with the screen instead of remaining in the same place.

Here is the code I'm using:

```css
.it {
  display: inline;
  cursor: default;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
  <p class="it" id="hst">Home</p>
  <p class="it" id="ft">Friends</p>
  <p class="it" id="pt">Profile</p>
  <p class="it" id="nt">Notifications</p>
</div>
```

here's a link to a video that shoes the problem:
[the link:](https://youtube.com/shorts/Y65R5chnUq8)

Comment: We need a [mcve] please

Comment: Add image/draft of the final output you want to achieve. Your provided code didn't work either.

Comment: I just tested your code by adding `height` to`#scroll` and giving the `.it` 1 opacity, it's working fine!

Comment: @fevid Hi, can you please send me the code you wrote? i've added  `height: 50` to `#scroll` and nothing happend (I have a js code the handles the opacity of  `.it`) Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

here is the codes mentioned

```css
.it {
  display: inline;
  cursor: default;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#scroll{
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgb(0,36,18);
  background: linear-gradient(183deg, rgba(0,36,18,1) 0%, rgba(9,89,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,255,177,1) 100%); 
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
  <p class="it" id="hst">Home</p>
  <p class="it" id="ft">Friends</p>
  <p class="it" id="pt">Profile</p>
  <p class="it" id="nt">Notifications</p>
</div>
```